# Salvaging Howson's theorem for free profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

This is an attempt to find a correct version of [Do free profinite groups satisfy Howson's theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195166/do-free-profinite-groups-satisfy-howsons-theorem?rq=1)

Let $F$ be a free profinite group, and let $A,B \leq F$ be closed finitely generated subgroups which (topologically) generate $F$ (i.e. the closure of the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$ is $F$).

> Must $A \cap B$ be (topologically) finitely generated?

Some intuition comes from the fact that the previous counterexample from [Do free profinite groups satisfy Howson's theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195166/do-free-profinite-groups-satisfy-howsons-theorem?rq=1) does not work here. Additional motivation is the fact that in the classical Howson's theorem (where $F$) is an abstract free group the additional condition $\langle A \cup B \rangle = F$ holds withou loss of generality since a subgroup of a free group is free. Hence, the same holds in the pro-$p$ case (for any prime $p$) where there exists an analogous theorem.